# Set of scripts to manage OpenStack nodes with euca2ools

Tags: openstack, cloud-computing

I'm writing some shell scripts based on [euca2ools](https://github.com/eucalyptus/euca2ools) to manage [OpenStack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStack) nodes. I feel that most of them are of general interest and not specific to my tasks, such as

- list/kill all defective nodes (= no IP or cannot be a SSH into)
- computing the number of RAM/CPU core each user in a project has
- displaying the number of instances for each user
- etc

Is there any libraries or repositories containing such useful common scripts to manage OpenStack nodes with euca2ools? I don't have any strong preference regarding the programming language: shell, python, etc., anything would be useful.

Comment: If anyone has any idea please add an answer.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far.